# Website users often report ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: domain-name-system, http, timeout

Users are often reporting that they can't access to my website because of a timeout error. I have experienced that issue as well, and it resolves after waiting a couple of hours or by using a VPN.

How can I find out why is it happening so often? Could it be a DNS related issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a bandwidth limit per day or something? (Are you hosted?)

Comment: @Smock I'm on a digitalocean vps. No bandwith limit as far as I know.